# Complex State Monad Structure

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I am still a newbie to Haskell and I think I am over my head right now. I have code that looks like the following.

```
data World = World {
  intStack :: [Int],
  boolStack :: [Bool]
} deriving Show

instance IntStack World where
   getIntStack = intStack
   putIntStack ints (World _ bools) = World ints bools

instance BoolStack World where
    getBoolStack = boolStack
    putBoolStack bools (World ints _) = World ints bools

class IntStack a where
    getIntStack :: a -> [Int]
    putIntStack :: [Int] -> a -> a

class BoolStack a where
    getBoolStack :: a -> [Bool]
    putBoolStack :: [Bool] -> a -> a

(<=>) :: (IntStack c, BoolStack c) => c -> c
(<=>) w = putIntStack xs . putBoolStack ((x == x'):bs) $ w
    where (x:x':xs) = getIntStack w
          bs = getBoolStack w

(<+>) :: (IntStack c) => c -> c
(<+>) w = putIntStack ((x+x'):xs) w
    where (x:x':xs) = getIntStack w
```

My focus (For now ignoring error cases in the functions) is being able to chain together functions like (<=>) and (<+>)  assuming that the underlying data type implements the function's required interfaces.

I feel like I can clean this up a lot with a state monad, but I am not sure how to structure it to allow changes to whatever data type that implements IntStack, BoolStack, etc..

I know that this is a horribly vague description, but I feel like the code I have above is probably the absolutely wrong way to go about it.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class IntStack a where
    getIntStack :: a -> [Int]
    putIntStack :: [Int] -> a -> a

class BoolStack a where
    getBoolStack :: a -> [Bool]
    putBoolStack :: [Bool] -> a -> a
```

Congratulations, you've just invented lenses! Abstract the `[Int]` and `[Bool]` types, and use `data` instead of `class`, and you get something like

```
data Lens a b = Lens
    { get :: a -> b
    , put :: b -> a -> a
    }
```

...which is implemented in half a dozen packages on Hackage. Most offer at least:

- the ability to derive projection lenses like your `getIntStack`/`putIntStack` and `getBoolStack`/`putBoolStack` directly from a data declaration
- horizontal composition (running first one lens, then a second lens -- e.g. first picking a `World` out of some larger structure, then picking the `intStack` out of the `World`) and vertical composition (running two lenses in parallel, each on one side of a pair)
- some interface with `State` and `StateT` (e.g. something of type `Lens a b -> State b r -> State a r`), which would let you write computations on a `[Bool]` or `[Int]` and run them as if they were computations on a `World`

So, check out hackage! There's the `data-lens` family, which includes [a core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens), [the deriving ability](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-template), and [the stateful interface](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-fd); the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lenses) package; and the [pointless-lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-lenses) package. There are probably some I forgot, too.

Comment: Yay, I also (re)invented lenses!  I'm pulling the packages from hackage now. +1

Comment: Thanks so much for this, absolutely mind blowing to me how useful these are.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement push and pop operations in the state monad, and use them to implement your functions:

```
popInt :: IntStack c => State c Int
popInt = do
  (x:xs) <- getIntStack <$> get
  modify $ putIntStack xs
  return x

pushInt :: IntStack c => Int -> State c ()
pushInt x = do
  xs <- getIntStack <$> get
  modify $ putIntStack (x:xs)

(<+>) :: IntStack c => State c ()
(<+>) = do 
  x <- popInt
  x' <- popInt
  pushInt (x + x')
```